# Rentrant but thread unsafe code

Tags: reentrancy

I have read that reentrancy doesn't imply thread safety.
Can anyone please provide an ***example of code*** which is re-entrant but thread unsafe. Apparently, Wikipedia has an example but i don't get it. Also, an explanation would be great.

P.s this is the wikipedia example

```
int t;


    void swap(int *x, int *y)
    {
     int s;

     s = t; // save global variable
     t = *x;
     *x = *y;
     // hardware interrupt might invoke isr() here!
     *y = t;
     t = s; // restore global variable
    }

    void isr()
    {
     int x = 1, y = 2;
     swap(&x, &y);
    }
```

Comment: Consider what happens if two threads execute that function simultaneously.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth I think you mean that the global variable t will have an unpredictable value depending on which thread updates it. But doesn't that make it non-reentrant as well ?

Comment: No, but the article specifically mentions that its **perfectly re-entrant**.All i want is an example which is re-entrant and not thread safe

Comment: Yes, and that example is one!  In a single-threaded environment, there are no problems.